# httpclient 502 error xamarin app trasnfering photo via json

Tags: json, xamarin.forms, dotnet-httpclient, http-status-code-502

We are getting 502 error when we try to send photo in Json.
App developed with .NET and Xamarin.Form

```
var jsonObjGuid = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ObjGuid);
var jsonObjFiles = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ObjFiles, Formatting.Indented);
var url = $"{ Session.EndpointURL}{MethodNames.UploadDossierFiles.Value}";

try
{
    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TransferEncodingChunked = true;
        httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(600000);

        using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url))
        {
            //request.Headers.Add(HeaderKeys.UserAgent.Value, Resources.DefaultUserAgent);
            request.Headers.Add(HeaderKeys.UserAgent.Value, "MobileApp");
            request.Headers.Add(HeaderKeys.Token.Value, token);

            HttpContent ObjGuidContent = new StringContent(jsonObjGuid);
            HttpContent ObjFilesContent = new StringContent(jsonObjFiles);

            MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent
                {
                    {ObjGuidContent, "ObjGuid"},
                    {ObjFilesContent, "ObjFiles"}
                };

            request.Content = content;
            var response = await Policy.HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(message => !message.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                .WaitAndRetryAsync(3, i => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), (result, timeSpan, retryCount, context) => { })
                .ExecuteAsync(() => httpClient.SendAsync(request));
        }
    }
}
```

Sometimes it works but often I get this error.
Any help, suggestions? What do I need to check?

Comment: this is a server error.  You need to look at your server logs to determine what is going wrong

Comment: the error is given by APP

Comment: a 502 is an HTTP response code returned by the server